# Decoding problems when receiving data over a serial port using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a problem receiving data from a serial port. My goal is to send data from my Arduino board and receive this data via a Python script.

At the moment it looks like the data will be sent successfully, but I still have problems receiving it. This is the current status of my code:

```
import serial
import time
import datetime

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=1)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    # reading is a string
    data = ser.readline()
    data_encode = data.decode('ascii')

    # time_diff = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
    # execution_time = str(time_diff.total_seconds())
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(data_encode))
```

The problem is this:
When I run a `print(data)` my output looks like this:

```
connected to: COM3
b'\r0\r\n'
b'0\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
b''
b'350\r\n'
b'350350\r\n'
b'350\r\n'
...
```

So it semms, that some of the data is faulty. I should always recive `b'350\r\n'` but sometimes it messes up. Is there anythink in my code which causes this problem or is this out of my hands and i have to filter it out?

My second question is:
If i call a `print(data_encode)` i get an output like this:

```
connected to: COM3


350


350


350


350


...
```

So im getting spaces between my values which i dont want. How can i get rid of these, because i want to store the data in an txt file and it should look like this:

```
350
350
350
350
...
```

I assume i have these spaces because of the `\r\n` when i decode `b'350\r\n'`, so isn't decode the right way to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Make sure arduino send data with "\n". At python receive you can use this to remove white space reply = ser.readline().decode().strip()

Comment: @WWJ Thanks for your prompt reply. `strip()` works perfectly!